# Проблема с воспроизведением звука с jar файла

Tags: java, многопоточность, аудио, mediaplayer, mp3

Есть проблема с воспроизведением звука. Работаю в IDEA, там всё нормально играет. Если запущу в скомпиленом `jar` файле то не играет ничего. Подскажите почему? Сам файл находится у меня на рабочем столе, не в jar файле.

использую java Layev и mp3spi

Спасибо.

Код:

Music.java:

```
import com.tsyklop.area.Area;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

/**
 * @author Connor Mahaffey
 *         <p>
 *         This class is a rewrite of the example from: http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html
 *         <p>
 *         This class needs the following libraries:
 *         JLayer - http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html
 *         MP3 SPI - http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html
 *         Tritonus Share (tritonus_share-0.3.6.jar) - http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html
 *         <p>
 *         All credit goes to the creators of JLayer, MP3 SPI, and Tritonus.
 *         <p>
 *         This simple re-write adds loop, mute, pause, restart, and stop methods to the example mentioned above.
 *         <p>
 *         This code is completely free to use for any purpose whatsoever. JLayer, MP3 SPI, and Tritonus are
 *         all released under the LGPL.
 *         <p>
 *         <p>
 *         Known Issues:
 *         <p>
 *         - Though using .stop() and then .play() *technically* works for restarting the audio, doing this too fast
 *         causes problems because the old audio stream is never stopped (writing to the audio line takes a bit,
 *         and it can't be stopped once it's started).
 *         - Distorted audio (rarely? Problem with code or with audio APIs?)
 *         - General Efficiency
 */
public class Music implements Runnable {

    private File FILE;
    private boolean RUNNING, mute, pause, loop, restart, reduce;
    private final int byteChunkSize = 1024;//number of bytes to read at one time
    private byte[] muteData;

    private static Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger(Music.class);

    private FloatControl gainControl;

    /**
     * Declares default variable values.
     */
    public Music() {
        FILE = null;
        RUNNING = false;
        mute = false;
        pause = false;
        loop = false;
        restart = false;
        reduce = false;
        muteData = setMuteData();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a FILE object. If the FILE path exists on the system, the given FILE is an mp3, and
     * a song is not currently playing in this instance of the program, true is returned.
     *
     * @param file Path to the FILE.
     * @return If the FILE is loaded or not.
     */
    public boolean loadFile(File file) {
        FILE = file;
        if (FILE.exists() && FILE.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3") && !RUNNING) {
            return true;
        } else {
            FILE = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts playing the audio in a new thread.
     */
    public void play() {
        if (FILE != null && !RUNNING) {
            RUNNING = true;
            try {
                Thread t = new Thread(this);
                t.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Could not start new thread for audio!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pauses the audio at its current place. Calling this method once pauses the audio stream, calling it
     * again unpauses the audio stream.
     */
    public void pause() {
        if (FILE != null) {
            if (pause) {
                pause = false;
            } else {
                pause = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the audio stream. This method takes some time to execute, and as such you should never call
     * .stop() followed immediately by .play(). If you need to restart a song, use .restart().
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (FILE != null) {
            RUNNING = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stream continues to play, but no sound is heard. Calling this method once mutes the audio stream,
     * calling it again unmutes the audio stream.
     */
    public void mute() {
        if (FILE != null) {
            if (mute) {
                mute = false;
            } else {
                mute = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void reduce() {
        if (FILE != null) {
            reduce = !reduce;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes a given audio FILE loop back to the beginning when the end is reached. Calling this method once
     * will make it loop, calling it again will make it stop looping, but will not stop the audio from playing
     * to the end of a given loop.
     */
    public void loop() {
        if (FILE != null) {
            if (loop) {
                loop = false;
            } else {
                loop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restarts the current song. Always use this method to restart a song and never .stop() followed
     * by .play(), which is not safe.
     */
    public void restart() {
        restart = true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not a clip will loop when it reaches the end.
     *
     * @return Status of the variable loop.
     */
    public boolean isLooping() {
        return loop;
    }

    /**
     * Returns if the audio is muted or not.
     *
     * @return Status of mute variable.
     */
    public boolean isMuted() {
        return mute;
    }

    /**
     * Returns if the audio is paused or not.
     *
     * @return Status of pause variable.
     */
    public boolean isPaused() {
        return pause;
    }

    /**
     * Returns if audio is currently playing (if the audio is muted, this will still be true).
     *
     * @return If the thread is RUNNING or not.
     */
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return RUNNING;
    }

    /**
     * Returns if a FILE is loaded or not.
     *
     * @return File status of null or a FILE.
     */
    public boolean isLoaded() {
        if (FILE == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the audio stream information and starts the stream. When the stream ends, this method
     * checks to see if it should loop and start again.
     */
    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                restart = false;
                LOGGER.info("Audio file - "+FILE);
                AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(FILE);
                AudioInputStream din = null;
                AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
                AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                        16,
                        baseFormat.getChannels(),
                        baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                        false);
                din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

                stream(decodedFormat, din);

                in.close();
            } while ((loop || restart) && RUNNING);
            RUNNING = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Problem getting audio stream!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Small sections of audio bytes are read off, watching for a call to stop, pause, restart, or mute the audio.
     *
     * @param targetFormat Format the audio will be changed to.
     * @param din          The audio stream.
     */
    private void stream(AudioFormat targetFormat, AudioInputStream din) {
        try {
            byte[] data = new byte[byteChunkSize];
            SourceDataLine line = getLine(targetFormat);
            if (line != null) {
                gainControl = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

                line.start();
                int nBytesRead = 0;
                while (nBytesRead != -1 && RUNNING && !restart) {
                    nBytesRead = din.read(data, 0, data.length);
                    if (nBytesRead != -1) {
                        if (mute) {
                            line.write(muteData, 0, nBytesRead);
                        } else {
                            line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                    if(reduce) {
                        gainControl.setValue(-3); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
                    } else {
                        gainControl.setValue(6); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
                    }
                    while (pause && RUNNING) {
                        wait(15);
                    }
                }
                line.drain();
                line.stop();
                line.close();
                din.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Problem playing audio!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the line of audio.
     *
     * @param audioFormat The format of the audio.
     * @return The line of audio.
     */
    private SourceDataLine getLine(AudioFormat audioFormat) {
        SourceDataLine res = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);

        try {
            res = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            res.open(audioFormat);
            res.drain();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not get audio line!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Waits a specified number of milliseconds.
     *
     * @param time Time to wait (in milliseconds).
     */
    private void wait(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not wait!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a byte array of all zeros to "play" when audio is muted. This produces no sound.
     *
     * @return Byte array of all zeros.
     */
    private byte[] setMuteData() {
        byte[] x = new byte[byteChunkSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = 0;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

JavaMusicExample.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Connor Mahaffey
 */
public class JavaMusicExample {

    /**
     * See the Music Class for details.
     * <p>
     * This is a simple program to show off the capabilities of the Music class.
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Tsyklop\\Desktop\\media\\51.mp3";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Music MU = new Music();

        if (filePath == null) {
            System.out.println("No path to a .mp3 in arguements.");
            loadMP3(MU);
        } else {
            if (!MU.loadFile(new File(filePath))) {
                System.err.println("Invalid path!");
                loadMP3(MU);
            }
        }

        do {
            System.out.println("1. Play");
            System.out.println("2. Pause");
            System.out.println("3. Mute");
            System.out.println("4. Restart");
            System.out.println("5. Stop");
            System.out.println("6. Load");
            System.out.println("7. Loop");
            System.out.println("8. Reduce");
            System.out.println("9. Exit");
            System.out.print("> ");
            input = in.nextLine();

            if (input.equals("1")) {
                MU.play();
            } else if (input.equals("2")) {
                MU.pause();
            } else if (input.equals("3")) {
                MU.mute();
            } else if (input.equals("4")) {
                MU.restart();
            } else if (input.equals("5")) {
                MU.stop();
            } else if (input.equals("6")) {
                MU.stop();
                loadMP3(MU);
            } else if (input.equals("7")) {
                MU.loop();
            } else if (input.equals("8")) {
                MU.reduce();
            } else if (input.equals("9")) {
                MU.stop();
            } else {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry.");
            }
        } while (!input.equals("9"));

        System.exit(0);

    }

    /**
     * Gets a file path from the program's arguements.
     *
     * @param args Arguements.
     * @return The path.
     */
    private static String getPathFromArgs(String[] args) {
        String s = null;

        try {
            s = args[0];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //no arguements
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Gets user command-line input and tries to load a MP3 from the path given.
     *
     * @param MU Music Object Reference
     */
    private static void loadMP3(Music MU) {
        boolean validPath;
        String filePath;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Path to .mp3: ");
            filePath = in.nextLine();
            validPath = MU.loadFile(new File(filePath));
            if (!validPath) {
                System.out.println("Invalid path!");
            }
        } while (!validPath);
    }

}
```

Comment: При помощи чего собирашь проект в jar файл?

Comment: @GVArt при помощи IDEA.